# Hosting ActiveX control in WPF: WindowsFormsHost or ActiveXHost?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, activex

I know MSDN [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx) to use [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) to host ActiveX controls in a WPF application. But there is also [ActiveXHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.activexhost.aspx), used as a base for WebBrowser control. It is described as an infrastructure class, yet it is **public** and I could derive from it. It seems to offer everything I might need to host a custom ActiveX control. Why have another layer? Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a WPF application which i assume it is the case then you should use `WindowsFormsHost` control to host your ActiveX content. The `WebBrowser` inherits from `ActiveXHost` to allow you to host ActiveX content in XAML applications that run inside web browsers which raises certain trust and security issues.

If you look at the inheritance tree you will find that both host derive from `HwndHost` but the `WindowsFormsHost` is intended for developers to use.

Anyway and as @Abe said, nothing truly dangerous might happen but if the guys at MSFT said not to do so then don't.

Comment: Did you mean `WebBrowser` rather than `BrowserControl`? I just could not find `BrowserControl`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason why you shouldn't use it is that as an infrastructure class, they won't ensure that the api is stable between releases. They could radically alter how it is supposed to be used even in a minor updated to the framework. Now, they probably won't, but since you have no guarantee that it will be stable, your application may suddenly break on a user's machine seemingly (to them) at random if a new version of .NET breaks the api.

I am not convinced this **will** happen, but that is the danger.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. It is just not clear why they left it _public_. The only descendent of it is WebBrowser from the same assembly. They sealed WebBrowser class and they could have marked ActiveXHost as _internal_, but they did not.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it does seem a bit strange. Maybe the developer in charge of that class just didn't want to write documentation for it, so decided it was "for internal use only" haha.